# c++ string comparison fails to compile

Tags: visual-c++

Is there a reason why the following code doesn't compile in VC++ 2013? I get the "internal error has occurred in the compiler" message.

```
if (string{} == string{})
  cout << "good\n";
```

Strangely, if the second `string{}` is replaced by `string()`, then this compiles successfully.

Comment: What do you mean by `string{}`? Is this C++11 initializer lists?

Comment: For the record, `g++` appears to handle this snippet fine and outputs `good`.

Comment: @Ben: it's C++11 uniform initialization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization

Comment: This could be a VS bug as pointed out by Paul below. My version of VS is 12.0.21005.1

Comment: @chakrapani Mine is 12.0.30501.0, try to install Update 2, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My VS2013 Update 2 compiles the following code successfully:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    if (string{} == string{})
        cout << "good\n";
}
```

What you get is a bug in the compiler and the compiler clearly tells you so:

> internal error has occurred in the compiler

If it was malformed code you should have had an error describing what's wrong with your code.

You can try to re-layout the code around those lines to make it compile.